# Django model with multiple foreign keys

Tags: python, django

I want to create a list of products that are categorized by area, need, and product category. I created 3 separate models that reply on each other so users will easily add categories and select from the dropdown list area and need.

For now, I have 3 areas and under each area I have needs. What I want is to render a list of items from `Area` model, under each item from `Area` model all items from `Need` model and under each item from `Need` model all items from `Product` model (only titles).

`ProductCategory` model is not used here but I need it somewhere else and it is a connector between products and areas/needs. It is much easier to define categories and just select them from the dropdown list when adding a new product.

I need to create a loop that will show me something like above. I know it will not work but I wanted to show the logic.

My question is what is the best approach to render something like this?

How can I get `category_area` and `category_need` in my class and in my html?

models.py

```
class Area(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=False)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='-', blank=False)
    publish = models.DateTimeField('publish', default=timezone.now)   

class Need(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=False, null=False, help_text='max 75 characters')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='-', blank=False)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    need_area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='need_area')

class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False, null=False, help_text='max 400 characters')
    body = models.TextField(default='-')
    publish = models.DateTimeField('publish', default=timezone.now)
    category_area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_area', null=True)
    category_need = models.ForeignKey(Need, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_need', null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=False)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete = models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name='products')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("product", kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

views.py

```
class SearchProducts(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = 'login'
    template_name = 'hubble/search/manual_search.html'
    model = Product
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super(SearchProducts, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            product_results = ProductCategory.objects.prefetch_related("products").all()
            context['product_results'] = product_results
            return context
```

product_search.html

```
    <div>
    {% for area in product_results %}
        <h6>{{area.title}}</h6>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) all backwards relationship and make an iteration similar to this:

```
areas = Area.objects.prefetch_related('need_area__category_need__products')

for area in areas:
    # iterate through each instance of Area
    for need in area.need_area.all():
        # iterate through  each instance of Need for the given area
        for product_category in need.category_need.all():
            # iterate through each instance of ProductCategory for the given need
            for product in product_category.products.all():
                # iterate through each instance of product for the given product category
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. Is it possible to filter areas, needs, categories so they appear only if there is at least 1 product?